# USB Modem Network Mode/Type

Tags: command-line, networking, modem, 3g

I'm using a Huawei E173 USB modem. With `comgt sig` I can easily get the network's signal strength, but I didn't find a way to specify which type of network is used (either GSM, Edge, or UMTS). Is there a way to do this via commandline?